# Calling a protected method for a member object in C++

Tags: c++, protected

If i have two classes, for example like this

```
class A {
    ...
    protected:
        B* test;
        aFunction();
};

class B {
    ...
    protected:
        A* test1;

    public:
        bFunction();
};
```

can I do this inside `bFunction()` of class B:

```
bFunction(){
    test1->aFunction();
}
```

Basically, can I call a protected function of a certain class from the class that's not derived from that function?

Comment: Why don't you try and see it ?

Comment: Only one answer to that: No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "point" of the `protected` is that only classes that are derived from the baseclass can call those functions.

If you have a good reason to do this, then make the class a `friend`, e.g. add `friend class B;` inside `class A`.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to avoid such inevident mutual dependencies. A necessity to use friend functions often indicates bad architecture.

Answer (score 1):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/):

> Private and protected members of a class cannot be accessed from
>   outside the same class in which they are declared. However, this rules
>   does not affect friends.

You can call protected and privat methods from other classes, when those are 'friends':

In your case that would be:

```
Class A {
    ...
    protected:
        B* test;
        aFunction();
    friend class B;
}
```

Often that is considered bad practice, but for tightly coupled classes that is ok.